# Single-button shortcut for "Do not Disturb"

Tags: macos, command-line, automation, keybindings

Is there a way I can bind a single key on my keyboard to toggle "Do not Disturb"?

It would be more convenient that opening up the notification center and moving that awkward slider.

I do think that you can bind a key to a script, so a command line option for "Do not Disturb" would work as well, so if there is a command-line tool to enable/disable "Do not Disturb" then I will take that as an answer (since I am muy familiar with bash and applescript).

Comment: Here is a ruby script that needs you to pass an "on/off" but it uses the correct manner of applescript simulating the mouse actions. Just writing to the plist using bash directly doesn't do everything the UI does on 10.11, so I don't use `defaults write` to make this change directly anymore - https://gist.github.com/samnung/c7e767167cf70531ccdc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down the Option key and click on the Notifications icon in the menu bar.

Comment: That's great, but I'm looking for a single key to do this without the mouse.

Comment: Go to System Preferences>Keyboard and select Mission Control. Tick the Do Not Disturb On/Off box then add your own button combination. Mine is Control Shift D. Granted its not a single button shortcut, but you don't have to load a script or anything for it.

Comment: Thanks!  ^ This one actually worked very very well.  In fact, it worked better than the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Download the ruby script from https://gist.github.com/samnung/c7e767167cf70531ccdc and then just make a bash wrapper to call it.

```
do_not_disturb.rb on
```

You'll may want a tool like [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to call the script (and if so, place your bash calling script in ~/Library/Scripts for it to show up there nicely)

Comment: And it runs from the command line just fine, so I'll throw it in as a bind.

Comment: Adding it as a bind was difficult, and that didn't work well so I just tossed the idea.  @simon 's answer worked well.